# MPLab / C prg / Variables

Tags: variables, mplab

I have MPLab V8.43 installed and just installed the C18 complier for programming.
Whenever I try and build a small test code it halts at the first variable declaration.  It says there is a syntax.

```
unsigned char counter;
```

doesn't look wrong to me...even did it as unsigned char counter[1];  and it still tossed a syntax error back at me.
What gives?  Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind...turns out you can't declare from within the main function in embedded world.

Comment: Not true, you can declare from within the main function in C, including the embedded world.  It just has to be at the top of a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local variables must be declared at the top of a block (in this case, a function.)  This is according to the C89 standard.

These are acceptable:

```
void functionname(void)
{
    unsigned char counter;

    /* rest of code */
}

void functionname(void)
{
    /* code */

    for (unsigned char counter = 0; counter<30; counter++)
    {
    }

}
```

This is not acceptable:

```
void functionname(void)
{
    /* code */

    unsigned char counter = 0; 

    /* more code */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As You have counter variable with char datatype. But its not an array or string.

```
  so you can't access it by counter[1].
```

Comment: I don't see in his original question where he's trying to access it with counter[1].  Perhaps it was edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can define local variables in main, but they should be defined, such that they don't follow the variable assignment block or the code execution block.

This is a valid variable declaration/defintion in MPLAB C18:

```
void main ()
{
    /* Declare or Define all Local variables */
    unsigned char counter;   
    unsigned char count = 5;

    /* Assignment Block or the code Execution Block starts */ 
    conter++;
    count++; 
}
```

However, this isn't valid, and will cause a ‘Syntax Error’:

```
void main ()
{
    /* Declare or Define all Local variables */
    unsigned char count = 5;

    /* Assignment Block or the code Execution Block starts */ 
    count++; 

    /* What??? Another variable Declaration / Definition block */ 
    unsigned char counter;     /* Hmmm! Error: syntax error */ 
}
```

Hope that helps!